# how it produce multiple token for each lexeme?

Tags: compiler-theory

I just started reading The Dragon Book and I'm finding difficulty in understanding some statements.

It says:  "lexical analyser produce sequence of token for each lexeme in the source program".  Can you please help me to understand the above line?  I know about tokens and lexemes, but what is meant by producing multiple token for each lexeme....AFAIK LEXEME itself compromising a single token.

The complete quote is as follows:

> "As the first phase of compiler, the main task of the Lexical Analyser is to read the input characters of the source program, group them into lexemes, and produce as output a sequence of tokens for each lexeme in the source program."

The above quote is from chapter 3..section 3.1 under the heading "role of lexical analyser" page number is 109

Comment: Exact quote (preferably with some context) and/or line and page number would help.

Comment: You've mangled the quote from the dragon book sufficiently such that I don't think I can guess what it's trying to say.  Are you able to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Tokens usually correspond one-to-one with lexemes. Try re-parsing that sentence as the "...and produce as output a sequence of tokens **for the lexemes** in the source program." That is the meaning the authors intended, as I read it.

Comment: How can I help? I agree with your statement: "AFAIK LEXEME itself compromises a single token". The book isn't implying differently with the quoted sentence; it's just poorly phrased, that's all.